# Running protractor tests on jenkins

Tags: angularjs, selenium, gruntjs, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to generate reports for jenkins using jasmine-reporter plugin.

My protractor configuration is:

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 99999,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
framework: 'jasmine2',
specs: ['../test/e2e/**/*.js'],
onPrepare: function() {
   var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        filePrefix: 'test_results_e2e'
    }));
},

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    print: function() {}
}
};
```

File with tests report is generated , but the test fails with the following error:

```
Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:9000/# : retries looking for angular exceeded
```

I am using grunt. So I am defining two tasks, one for tests and the second one for dev. These two tasks are using different configurations files, and only difference is that executing "grunt test" should result with file report, while "grunt dev" executes tests and watches for changes. So if I run application with "dev" task then I am not getting any error. But still task "test" produces file with error.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you're seeing indicates that the page you are testing is not an Angular app. My best guess given the information you've provided is that your `grunt dev` task is starting the local server and serving your app on port 9000, which allows the tests to work properly, but your `grunt test` task does not start the local server, so your app isn't actually running on port 9000.